# Smooth-scrolling to URL on click event using function

Tags: jquery, slider, smooth-scrolling

The royalslider API has a rsSlideClick function which can be triggered on an event.

It looks like this:

```
    var slider = $('#royalSliderStart').data('royalSlider');
    slider.ev.on('rsSlideClick', function() {
```

An additional function to use smooth scrolling for anchor links within a list looks like this:

```
    $('ul.nav > a').bind('click',function(event){ 
              var $anchor = $(this); 
    $('html, body').stop().animate({ 
            scrollTop: $($anchor.attr('href')).offset().top 
            }, 1500); 
                event.preventDefault(); 
            });
```

I'm looking for solutions to use the smooth scroll function with the rsSlideClick function, preferably without referencing anchor links.

As an example of the solution, a user clicks on a given slide and it smooth scrolls down to another area of the page (by id perhaps).

Solutions?

---

Update 1:

HTML

```
<div class="container"> 
<ul class"nav"> 
<div class="royalSlider" id="royalSliderStart"> 
    <li class=”slide” target=”1”><slide #1></li> 
    <li class=”slide” target=”2”><slide #2></li> 
    <li class=”slide” target=”3”><slide #3></li> 
    <li class=”slide” target=”4”><slide #4></li> 
    <li class=”slide” target=”5”><slide #5></li> 
    <li class=”slide” target=”6”><slide #6></li> 
    <li class=”slide” target=”7”><slide #7></li> 
</div>
</ul> 
</div>
```

SCRIPT (DOES NOT WORK AS INTENDED. REQUIRES REVIEW.)

```
var slider = $('#royalSliderStart').data('royalSlider');
    slider.ev.on('rsSlideClick', function() {
            $('.slide').on('click',function(event){ 
                var el = $(this); 
                $('html, body').stop().animate({ 
                    scrollTop: $(el.attr('target')).offset().top 
                }, 1500); 
                event.preventDefault(); 
        }); 
    }); 
});
```

Comment: Question updated with revised code snippets (Update 1).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated:

```
$('.slide').on('click', function(event) { 
    var el = $(this);
    $('html, body').stop().animate({
        scrollTop: $(el.attr('target')).offset().top 
    }, 1500);
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

HTML

```
<ul class="nav">
    <li class="slide" target="#slide-1">Slide 1</li> 
    <li class="slide" target="#slide-2">Slide 2</li> 
    <li class="slide" target="#slide-3">Slide 3</li>
</ul> 
<div class="content" id="slide-1">Slide 1 content</div>
<div class="content" id="slide-2">Slide 2 content</div>
<div class="content" id="slide-3">Slide 3 content</div>
```

**[Demo jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/manoj_admlab/sU5Wz/1/)**

As royalSlider is removing html code and and adding slides, above will not work

*Updated Code for royalSlider

HTML

```
<div class="royalSlider rsDefault">
    <img src="http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/royal-slider/img/previews/home/visible-nearby.jpg">
    <img src="http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/royal-slider/img/previews/home/animated-blocks.jpg">
    <img src="http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/royal-slider/img/previews/home/fullwidth.jpg">
</div>
<div class="content" id="slide-1">Slide 1 content</div>
<div class="content" id="slide-2">Slide 2 content</div>
<div class="content" id="slide-3">Slide 3 content</div>
```

JS

```
$(".royalSlider").royalSlider({});
var slider = $(".royalSlider").data('royalSlider');
slider.ev.on('rsSlideClick', function() {
    $('html, body').stop().animate({
        scrollTop: $('#slide-' + slider.currSlideId).offset().top
    }, 1500);
});
```

**[jsFiddle for royalSlider](http://jsfiddle.net/manoj_admlab/7Lpha/)**

Comment: Could you explain #slideID as I have more than 20 slides.

Comment: Then add a class `slide` to all of them and target as attribute then use it as selector, Answer updated

Comment: could you review the update I posted because it is still not working. The update contains snippets for a better understanding.

Comment: Manoj your code is perfect, but the problem I think is with the way the rsClickSlide function is trying to use the scroll function. It won't initialize. 

This is that code:

var slider = $('#royalSliderStart').data('royalSlider');
    slider.ev.on('rsSlideClick', function() {

Comment: Add the above JS code at the end and not in `slider.ev.on('rsSlideClick', function() { });` then try

Comment: Requesting clarification

Comment: Perhaps need to make a public function then call have rsSlideClick call it?

Comment: This is very good Manoj. I'm trying it out now. I'll post back with the results soon.

Comment: Perfect solution. This is the answer. Manoj Yadav is a good communicator, understands requirements, and performs exceptionally well in difficult conditions. As an example, provided with only limited code snippets he was able to thoroughly research, analyze and solve a complex problem, and did so accurately. Manoj Yadav is highly recommended for any PHP, Magento, or jQuery work.